# JavaFx Customzied CategoryAxis manual without useing AutoRanging

Tags: charts, javafx-2

I have a Chart which may have null value and also i want Fixing X-Axis Scale (ex.20 point).
and the value binding to Y-Axis (not null value ex.10 value).

[image: My desired Chart]

[Update]

```
String [] categories = {"32-11, 33-11, 34-11, 35-11, 36-11, 37-11, 38-11, 39-11, 40-11, 41-11, 42-11, 43-11, 44-11, 45-11, 46-11, 47-11, 48-11, 49-11, 50-11, 51-11"};
LineChart<String, Number> myChart;
CategoryAxis xAxis;
NumberAxis yAxis;

yAxis = new NumberAxis();
xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(categories))); 
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

myChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    Series<String, Number> aSeries = new Series<String, Number>();
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        aSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(categories[i],"Some Long values and may be null"));
    }

myChart.getData().add(aSeries);
```

- Chart draw Nothing
- //xAxis.setAutoRanging(false); Chart draw but with auto range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I found solution for my question :

- I get the CategoryAxis source ! from [CategorAxis](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/rt/file/5c3b3d524f07/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.java).
- And add one line all thing go right.

  ```
  public final void setCategories(ObservableList<String> value) {
  categories.set(value);
  invalidateRange(value);  //add that line
  requestAxisLayout();
  }
  ```

**Update:**

The problem can be solved without changing the CategoryAxis class just added that line to my code:

```
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false); 
xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(categories))); 
xAxis.invalidateRange(Arrays.asList(categories));  // add that line to my code.
```

Comment: When using **non empty constructor** xAxis = new `CategoryAxis(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(categories)));
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);`
As _Oracle docs_ **Create a category axis with the given categories.**
But it create axis ticks **without** any chart series line.

Comment: Can't we just set a count for category axis? for example, i only want 10 categories to show, when 11th category comes, first will be removed?